# Strange solution after dividing equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have $$3x=0$$ equation. I divided both sides of it by x and got: $$\frac{3x}{x} =\frac{0}{x}$$ $$3 = 0$$

I want to ask, how is that possible? What did I do wrong? Did I break any rule of math?

Comment: What if $x=0$? You cannot divide both sides by $0$...

Comment: You cant divide by $x$ unless you know that $x \ne 0$. Are you in this case?

Comment: If we are talking about an equation over a field like $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$, then $x=0$. If two things multiply to zero in a field like $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$, then at least one of them is $0$. And $3$ isn't zero, so...

Comment: See something similar in my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/984185/can-you-cancel-out-a-term-if-equal-to-zero/984190#984190).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, math broke today. :(

On a more serious note: The only solution to your equation $3x = 0$ is $x=0$. Now, since we cannot divide by zero, the operation

$$\frac{3x}{x} = \frac{0}{x}$$

is illegal. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you're assuming that $\frac{1}{x}$ exists. This is not a valid assumption since $x = 0$.

Remember that you really are multiplying b $x$ inverse, but $0$ has no inverse.

Answer (score 0):

I do not agree with the previous comments. There are no mistakes in the Ty221's post. Indeed, he shows that the equation $3x=0$ has no solutions in $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$.